# ListView - unable to make 2 columns

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using Iterateds.Properties;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Iterateds {
    public partial class Main : Form {
        public static readonly int Max = 10;
        public static List<string> Files = new List<string>();
        public static int CountFiles = 0,
                          Threaded = 0,
                          Counters = 0;
        public Main() {
            string File;
            StringReader strReader = new StringReader(Resources.files.Trim());
            while (null != (File = strReader.ReadLine())) {
                Files.Add(File);
            }
            CountFiles = Files.Count;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        public void Iterated() {
            if (0 >= Files.Count) {
                return;
            }
            string selectPath = this.selectPath?.Text;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectPath.Trim())) {
                return;
            }
            int Counter = 0;
            foreach (string file in Files) {
                if (Main.Counters >= Counter) {
                    ++Counter;
                    continue;
                }
                if (Max > Threaded) {
                    string filed = file.Trim();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filed)) {
                        continue;
                    }                    
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    //////////////////////////
                    // THE PROBLEM IS HERE: //
                    //////////////////////////
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(filed);
                        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar {
                            Maximum = 100
                        };
                        this.Logs.Items.Add(item);
                        Rectangle r = item.Bounds;
                        pb.SetBounds(r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
                        this.Logs.Controls.Add(pb);
                    ///////////////////////////////
                    // ^^ THE PROBLEM IS HERE ^^ //
                    ///////////////////////////////
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // here is the load manager, after we reach "Threaded" it starts "Iterated" again to take another "Max" or the remainder if less.
                    ++Threaded;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the first time is added, everything is fine, but I realized that they stick to the screen, after the next iteration, they no longer appear progressbars, or somewhere below in a bunch in 1 place, as if it were there 1, and the paths to the files themselves are displayed as needed.

The problem is probably due to `pb.SetBounds`, since `ListView` has a scrollbar, scrolling and everything collapses, maybe someone will tell you how to solve such a problem?

I need the file address on the left, and the progress bar on the right, nothing else is needed.
Each time the function should take no more than `Max`.
That is, only `Max` or less can be processed at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to solve without `ListView`, through `TableLayoutPanel`.

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1;
Label txt = new Label {
    Text = filed
};
txt.AutoSize = true;
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar {
    Maximum = 100
};
pb.Height = 10;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
```